# C Program - Finding the highest odd integer, stops when input a number less than 1.(Beginner)

Tags: c

I am currently taking programming classes this semester and at the moment we are using C language to program.

For this program it has to find the highest even integer among the values entered by the user. It stops asking values when a value less than 1 has been entered. If there is no even integer it should display "NO ODD INTEGER

at the moment this is what I have

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#define MAXNUMBERS 5

int find_maximum(int[], int);

int main()
{
    int c, array[MAXNUMBERS], location, maximum, amount_numbers;

    clrscr();

    amount_numbers = getNumbers(array);

    printf("Highest odd integer: ");
    for (c = 0 ; c < MAXNUMBERS ; c++)
    {
        location = find_maximum(array, MAXNUMBERS);
        maximum = array[location];
    }
    printf("%d", maximum);

    getch();
}

int find_maximum(int a[], int n) {
    int c, max, index;

    max = a[0];
    index = 0;

    for(c = 1 ; c < n ; c++) {
        if(a[c] > max && a[c] %1==1) {
            index = c;
            max = a[c];
        }
    }

    return index;
}

int getNumbers(int arr[])
{
    int c;
    int n = 0;
    printf("You may enter a max. %d numbers, enter a number less than 1 to end.\n", MAXNUMBERS);

    for(c = 0 ; c < MAXNUMBERS ; c++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &arr[c]);
        fflush(stdin);
        n++;
        if(arr[c] < 1)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    return n;
}
```

*Problem has been fixed question can be closed or deleted because of unecessary question

Comment: This problem can be solved without using arrays at all.

Comment: I notice you set `max = a[0];` but you don't know this element has an even value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest this approach :

```
int main()
{
    int c, array[MAXNUMBERS], maximum, amount_numbers;

    clrscr();

    getNumbers(array);



    location = find_maximum(array, MAXNUMBERS);
    if (location == -1 )
        printf("No Even integer");
    else {
        maximum = array[location];
        printf("Highest even integer :%d", maximum);
    }
    getch();
}
int find_maximum(int a[], int n) {
    int c, max, index;

    max = -10000; // A very low number
    index = -1; // shows that no even integer is found yet.

    for(c = 1 ; c < n ; c++) {
        if(a[c] > max && a[c] %2 == 0) {
            index = c;
            max = a[c];
        }
    }

    return index;
}
int getNumbers(int arr[])
{
    int c;
    printf("You may enter a max. %d numbers, enter a number less than 1 to end.\n", MAXNUMBERS);

    for(c = 0 ; c < MAXNUMBERS ; c++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &arr[c]);
        fflush(stdin);
        if(arr[c] < 1)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

You should first scan the array from the user which is what getNumbers function does.
Next you need to find the highest even integer which is what find_maximum funciton does.
this function returns index of the highest event integer in your array. the default value is -1 which indicates that no even value is found ! if it's given any other value means that found the highest even integer.
so now that you have the index you check if it's -1(not found) or it's found (returned index).

Answer (score 0):

There is no sense to define an array for a sequence of numbers with undefined size that to determine the maximum value. When a next number is entered you can compare it with the current maximum value provided that the entered number is even.

The program can look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
        int max = 0;
        int value;

        printf("Enter a sequence of integer numbers.\n"
            "Enter a number less than 1 to end: ");

        while (scanf("%d", &value) == 1 && !(value < 1))
        {
            if (value % 2 == 0 && max < value) max = value;
        }

        if (max != 0)
        {
            printf("Highest even integer: %d\n", max);
        }
        else
        {
            puts("No even integer");
        }
}
```

As for your program then this loop is wrong.

```
for (c = 0 ; c < MAXNUMBERS ; c++)
{
    location = find_maximum(array, MAXNUMBERS);
    maximum = array[location];
}
```

For starters the number of entered values can be less than `MAXNUMBERS`. You have to use at least the variable `amount_numbers` in the condition.

Moreover the loop is not needed Because it does the same that is it calls several times the function  `find_maximum` and nothing is changed with the function result between iterations of the loop. Moreover you have to check whether the variable `location` gets value 0 and whether the element with this index is less or greater than 1. Otherwise you can show invalid result.

Answer (score 0):

As commented, you are only required to output the answer so there is no need to store the input in an array. This shows how to do it with a simple loop. The program also ends at non-numeric input (effectively a 0 value).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int innum = 0;
    int maximum = 0;
    while(scanf("%d", &innum) == 1 && innum > 0) {
        if(innum % 2 == 0 && maximum < innum) {
            maximum = innum;
        }
    }

    if(maximum < 2) {
        puts("NO EVEN INTEGER");
    }
    else {
        printf("Highest even integer: %d\n", maximum);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Program session:

```
3 8 1 5 3 4 -5
Highest even integer: 8
```